# Python colormap in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I wish to use matplotlib's `cmap='bwr'` for in MATLAB (for e.g. `imagesc`), but that's not supported. Can it be "exported" from matplotlib into MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB enables customs via [colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#d126e226918)'s `map` that's a 3D array. Following [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#getting-colormaps-and-accessing-their-values), we generate such an array as shown below.

There's one tuning parameter (I called it `granularity`), that controls the size of the 3D array. Input values are mapped from minimum to maximum according to this array - inexact matches are interpolated, so greater `granularity` is more accurate but slower. How much is sufficient depends on `cmap`, and I've no clue what it is for any given `cmap`, but `256` seems decent (feel free to recommend others!).

Save in Py via `scipy.io.savemat`, load in Mat via `load`. There may be a way to just cache it, but I don't know how. Example use in a [`plt.imshow` port in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77301165/10133797).

For other libraries, e.g. `seaborn`, the idea's the same. If a library lacks an equivalent exporting method, one could dig in source code and find the mapper generator, or just plot the full color range and use a software to obtain the RGB values (which is what the 3D array is). If the colormap demands RGBA, this might be an issue, as Mat seems to only accept 3D, not 4D `map`.

```py
#%% Configs
cmap = 'bwr'
granularity = 255
savedir = ''

#%% Imports
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy.io import savemat

#%% Generate & save
cmap_gen = mpl.colormaps[cmap].resampled(granularity)
cmap_arr = cmap_gen(np.linspace(0, 1, granularity))
assert np.all(cmap_arr[:, 3] == 1)  # mat's 3D, we don't try to find workarounds
cmap_arr = cmap_arr[:, :3]
savemat(os.path.join(savedir, cmap + '.mat'), {'map': cmap_arr})
```