# Python's `imshow` in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do I recreate a basic `plt.imshow(x)` in MATLAB? `imshow` and `imagesc` don't work on arbitrary floating point data.

At minimum, `vmin` and `vmax` (color norm range) should also be replicated. Optionally, I'd like to be able to use some Python colormaps that aren't in MATLAB, especially `'bwr'` - is that doable?

Minimal-ish example below.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import ifft, ifftshift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate `x`
N, M = 2048, 512
wx, wy = np.linspace(0, 1, N, 0), np.linspace(0, 1, M, 0)
psi_x = ifftshift(ifft(np.exp(-(wx - .0125/2 )**2 * 2**19)))
psi_y = ifftshift(ifft(np.exp(-(wy - .00625*2)**2 * 2**16)))
x = psi_x * psi_y[:, None]

# make reusables
title_kw = dict(loc='left', weight='bold', fontsize=22)
mx = np.max(np.abs(x))

# plot
plt.imshow(x.real, cmap='bwr', vmin=-mx, vmax=mx, aspect='auto')
plt.title("Real part", **title_kw)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((8, 8))
plt.show()

plt.imshow(abs(x), cmap='turbo', vmin=0, vmax=mx, aspect='auto')
plt.title('Absolute value', **title_kw)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((8, 8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `imshow` works in arbitrary floating point data, but you need to tell it. `imshow(img, [0 mx])` is the same as `plt.imshow(img,vmin=0,vmax=mx)`. There are also quite good MATLAB FEX submissions for python colormaps, to make your life easier, and avoid needing to replicate work.

Comment: Thanks - I asked someone experienced and they seemed to suggest there's no such functionality and recommended `imagesc` instead, so I didn't bother looking in `imshow`. Though how's one resize? `imresize(, 'box')`? My method works fine with reproducing how `plt.imshow` handles e.g. `randn(9, 9)`.

Comment: Specifying an axis not supported? To work with e.g. [tiledlayout](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html)? I get one can maybe hack around it, but it's still a big downside to me to not directly specify an axis

Comment: Check the function `axes`. Matplotlib was based on MATLAB, so almost certainly you can always find a MATLAB equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, I just need to point this out: 'turbo' and other rainbow color maps are awful and should never be used. Since the 1980's people have been warning against this. [This paper](https://github.com/djoshea/matlab-utils/blob/master/libs/perceptuallyImprovedColormaps/Rainbow%20Color%20Map%20-Still-%20Considered%20Harmful.pdf) is a really good summary of the arguments. It took decades, but finally MATLAB's default color map was changed from "jet" to "parula", and Matplotlib also has a perceptually uniform default color map. There are many of those to choose from, don't pick 'turbo'.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Agreed on `jet`, disagreed on [`turbo`](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70642/50076) (see last comment). It's actually addressing your exact link - I've been wanting to be convinced otherwise. The "good" mappings are just not expressive enough to me. Thanks for that comment though, I value "pro tips" like these.

Comment: The rainbow color map has issues that cannot be fixed by smoother color transitions. Your absolute value plot looks very low in the middle, whereas I guess it's highest there. I also see distinct rings, which wouldn't be there with a better color map. Turbo might be better than jet, but it is still not a good color map. It still causes artificial boundaries to be seen, and it still has a dark color for the highest values. If you want to increase visibility of low-intensity lines (in the linked argument) use a gamma mapping.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Some good points. Re: dark=max - I've actually never thought of this before. It's also never been an issue for me. If maxima and minima aren't random gibberish, they should be discernible - you'd need data that suddenly jumps to very near maximum, so no near-redness, which is rare in many fields. Parula also has rings. `gray` doesn't, but is otherwise terrible IMO. Viridis doesn't, +1 (I might switch to that for some things). But for what I work with most - time-frequency plots - I don't think there's any better than `turbo`. What's "gamma mapping"?

Comment: I always use gray for images, it is the only way I can discern the shape of intensity profiles correctly. But everyone is different I guess. Gamma mapping is described [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction). I don’t like calling it “correction” because you’re not necessary correcting for anything, you’re just enhancing distinction of dark or bright colors.

Comment: @CrisLuengo _"I always use gray for images"_ hmm, I was gonna complain how it lacks discriminability near peaks, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DrSq.png) isn't as bad as I thought. Ok, not terrible. For time-freq though, it's still lacking - I often care for this ~10% it's squishing together. Thanks for the URL - I'm guessing it's not out-of-box in MATLAB (... but is in diplib!)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I retract "dark=max", I forgot I work with synchrosqueezing; try `plt.imshow([[0, 1, 0]], cmap='turbo')`. To those new to `turbo`, I can see how my example in question can yield min-max confusion, but I've never had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Below `imshow` fully reproduces the example in question.

Scaling `x` to within `[-255, 255]` and converting to `int32` makes it suitable for `imagesc`. The rest is matter of digging in various MATLAB docs:

- `vmin`, `vmax` are reproduced via [axis.CLim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clim.html).
- `figsize` is reproduced by manipulating [figure.Position](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html).
- `set_size_inches` - convert Python's inches to pixels via `fig.dpi * figsize` in Python (I've not quite tested this); there's also `figure.Units = 'inches'`, but that also affects the figure position
- `plt.title` is reproduced with [title](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html)
- `cmap` is reproduced by working with [colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html). Unsupported colormaps can be ported from Python as shown in below example.
- `set(ax, 'YDir', 'reverse')` to match Python's increasing vertical index from up to down. `imagesc` doesn't always do this by default, even if `'CData'` isn't specified (maybe a bug, though not in below code; I fetch `fig`, `ax` elsewhere)
- If using with existing `fig`, `ax` (e.g. subplots), may be more performant/proper to do `imagesc(ax, 'CData', x)` instead, but see [high-level vs low-level note](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html#bux1nfb-2)

[image]

#### Example reproduced

```matlab
% arguments
norm = [];
figsize = [500 500];

% generate `x`
N = 2048;
M = 512;
wx = linspace(0, 1-1/N, N);
wy = linspace(0, 1-1/M, M);
psi_x = ifftshift(ifft(exp(-(wx - .0125/2 ).^2 * 2^19)));
psi_y = ifftshift(ifft(exp(-(wy - .00625*2).^2 * 2^16)));
x = (psi_x) .* (psi_y.');

% plot
imshow(real(x), norm, 'Real part',      0, 'bwr',   figsize)
imshow(x,       norm, 'Absolute value', 1, 'turbo', figsize)
```

#### Porting colormaps

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77301149/10133797).

#### imshow

```matlab
function imshow(x, norm, title_txt, aval, cmap, figsize)    
    % handle input -------------------------------------------------------
    xa = abs(x);
    if aval
        x = xa;
    end
    % put the greater of minimum or maximum at 255
    scaling = 255 / max(xa, [], 'all');
    x = x * scaling;
    
    if ~isa(x, "int32")
        x = int32(x);
    end
    
    % basic plot ---------------------------------------------------------
    % generate canvas
    fig = figure;
    ax = gca;

    % `imshow`
    imagesc(ax, x);
    
    % styling meta -------------------------------------------------------
    % transform limits the same way
    if isempty(norm)
        if aval
            clims = [0 255];
        else
            clims = [-255 255];
        end
    else
        % matplotlib's `vmin`, `vmax` are specified w.r.t. `x`; 
        % below undoes this rescaling w.r.t. color norm
        clims = norm * scaling;
    end

    % styling ------------------------------------------------------------
    axis tight
    set(fig, 'color', 'white')  % white background
    set(ax, 'YDir', 'reverse')  % ensure y-axis increases from up to down
    
    % `title`
    if ~isempty(title_txt)
        title(title_txt)
        ax.TitleHorizontalAlignment = 'left';
    end
    
    % `cmap`
    try
        map = load([cmap, '.mat']).map;
    catch
        map = cmap;
    end
    colormap(fig, map)
    
    % `norm`
    ax.CLim = clims;
    
    % `figsize`
    if ~isnan(figsize)
        w = figsize(1);
        h = figsize(2);
        % get current [pos_x, pos_y, w, h]
        op = fig.Position;
    
        % set nans to current values
        if isnan(w)
            w = op(3);
        end
        if isnan(h)
            h = op(4);
        end
    
        % reuse old pos_x, pos_y (may not be optimal)
        fig.Position = [op(1:2), w, h];
    end
end
```

**What's in the plots?** [2D separable Morlet wavelet](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86013/50076)

Comment: Great answer, +1, but I still think its better to just use the appropiate MATLAB functions that do the same thing rather than overwrite `imshow` to look like python (and lose some functionality along the way)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't familiar with `imshow` - I found [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/72130-what-s-the-difference-between-imagesc-and-imshow) on the differences. I'll see if I'd like to reformulate it around `imshow` (one thing is `imagesc` seems to easier handle resizing).